# Slow simple single insert in MariaDB (MySQL) - 50 ms

Tags: mysql, insert, mariadb

*MariaDB could be thought as a fork of MySQL*

I have some software, written in C, which uses SQLite for some operations. I've implemented MySQL backend as an experiment to hasten DB performance. But surprisingly it was not too fast. Basically, I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  `time` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
)
```

There are no explicit foreign keys, no triggers on insert and so on. Then, the simple insert

```
INSERT INTO `events` (`type`, `time`) VALUES ('abc', '2013-04-19T10:00:00')
```

takes 50 ms to complete. It is very slow for me, and it means only 20 inserts in second - is this OK? Unfortunately, those inserts are non-relating with each other, and it is not easy to group them with bulk inserts or transactions.

Am I miss something, and those inserts should be much faster? Or it is the expected performance (isn't it very slow)?

For this test, I run both the software and MariaDB 10.0 on the same machine - Core i7 and Debian x64. DB was set up with all defaults. DB type is XtraDB (InnoDB).

I'm not expert with MySQL

I've found a related question: [mysql insert was too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280809/mysql-insert-was-too-slow)

Comment: MariaDB 10.0? That's still in development. I suggest you use version 5.5 (or 5.3). And you have a thorough check on the configuration settings.

Comment: And how sure are you that the 50ms is the database's fault and not your program's (e.g. opening and closing connections instead of keeping open one) or the network's fault (if server and program are not on the same machine)?

Comment: @ypercube I have two inserts in one connection. The second is performed on an opened connection, and it takes 40-50 ms to perform. The program logic during preparing the query, binding parameters and executing it is trivial.

Comment: How many entries are in the table?

Comment: @xsign It is the test, and the table is almost empty (0-100 rows).

Comment: Have you tried doing 100s or 1000s inserts and test speed? I don't think measuring one insert operation is useful.

Comment: And if you are going to have so many inserts, why not gather them in one `INSERT` statement (say per 100 rows) ?

Comment: @ypercube As I said, those inserts are non-relating with each other, and they can't be simple grouped. But if I won't find reasonable solution, I will have to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to implement some app-level transaction grouping logic to reach needed performance. As I understand now, this performance *is expected* for my hardware. Probably, it will be much better on server hardware (no time to test).

Again, as it seems, this performance is normal for single non-transaction-grouped insert. Bulk inserts, transactions etc. shows totally different speeds.

Answer (score -1):

instead of backticks in the values use single quotes

```
INSERT INTO `events` (`type`, `time`) VALUES ('abc', '2013-04-19T10:00:00')
```

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo. Really I use prepared queries.

Comment: What type? Client or server parsed? Does a non-prepared INSERT statement exhibit the same behaviour?

Comment: I don't know where these statements are parsed (I use default API). For plain queries (non-prepared), I tested now, and the performance is exactly the same.